# Sequelize - Inserting multiple associated entities in transaction fails

Tags: transactions, associations, sequelize.js

I have two models: Status and StatusParameter. Status 'hasMany()' StatusParameter and StatusParameter 'belongsTo()' Status. I want to insert a Status record and then insert multiple StatusParameter entities associated to the new Status. I want to wrap all the inserts in a transaction as well. I am using Sequelize 2.0.5, so here is what I came up with:

```
return sequelize.transaction(function(t) {
    return Status.create({name: 'abc', value: 1 }, {transaction: t}).then(function(instance) {
        return sequelize.Promise.all(
            [sequelize.models.StatusParameter.create({statusId:instance.id, name: 'myParamName', value:123}, {transaction: t}),
            sequelize.models.StatusParameter.create({statusId:instance.id, name: 'myOtherParamName', value:345}, {transaction: t})
            ]);
        });
    }).then(function(){
      // Automatically comitted at this point if the promise chain returned to the transaction successfully resolved
      callback();
    }).catch(function(err){
      // Automatically rolledback at this point if the promise chain returned to the transaction was rejected
      callback(err);
    });
```

Executing this code snippet will always get in the rollback scenario with a stack trace pointing to dialects/mssql/query.js line 66 with an error message stating this: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined

I have no clue why I get this, I looked at the query.js code but could not figure why the promise variable is undefined in this case, especially that if I insert only one new StatusParameter entity, all works fine. Its really when I  insert more than one associated entity that the error comes up.

Thanks!
Phil

Comment: Sequelize recently remove event-emitter support, but it was still present in 2.0.5. Have you tried re-installing sequelize and dependencies?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to try the latest tag. 2.1.0, it works just fine. I only had to use Promise.map with {concurrency:1} instead of Promise.all since tedious was complaining about executing two queries concurrently, will look into that later to see if I could concurrently add them and have a little performance gain. Thanks @jan!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the latest sequelize tag (not release) which was 2.1.0 at that time, as suggested by Jan, it works just fine but I only had to use Promise.map with {concurrency:1} instead of Promise.all since tedious (I am on a MS SQL Server DB) was complaining about executing two queries concurrently, will look into that later to see if I could concurrently add them and have a little performance gain. Thanks @jan!!